# can we use mobile's inbuit fingerprint scanner to store fingerprint in database

Tags: android, web, mobile, fingerprint

I want to make a website in which i want to verify a user by the fingerprint. I want to store the user fingerprint in database just by using mobile's fingerprint scanner, I don't want to use any external fingerprint scanner. Is it possible?

Comment: actually no, you cannot access the fingerprint data

Comment: you can not access the fingerprint data you can only do a validation through this

Comment: I want to scan the fingerprint at the time of registration and store it iin the database, and further use it for validation process. Like aadhar card , it is stored in database and when we do KYC process we have to give the fingerprint with external fingerprint scanner, but I don't want to use any external fingerprint scanner.